# Integrating existing app iOS 'React/RCTEventDispatcher.h' file not found on React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to integrate an existing app made in Obj-C with React Native. When i don't use any external library it builds successfully, but when i try to integrate with https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit (or any other library) it gives me this error:

```
'React/RCTEventDispatcher.h' file not found
```

Edit:

For some reason it can be fixed by changing the import from:

```
<React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
```

To:

```
"RCTEventDispatcher.h"
```

Comment: Hey @pedro neri, Do you found any solution for this

Comment: Yes, I changed the way the library was imported from <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h> to "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

Answer (score 1):

1- delete the app from my iPhone simulator and then go to Hardware -> Erase all content & settings.

2-  delete all your linked dependencies file in your iOS Podfile
(pod 'xxxxxxx', :path => '../node_modules/xxxxx)

3- close the Xcode, update the pod by writing “pod update” in your iOS folder and then run "react-native link" .

4- open Xcode and go to Menu -> Product -> Clean Build Folder  and then run the app in Xcode.

5- link manually the "react-native-gesture-handler" into your Xcode

6-run your app from Xcode